# How to do a callback in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-callback

I have two buttons "Save" and "Close".
I need the Close button to ask a question whether the user wants to save before it redirects back to the main page. The below code shows what I want to accomplish.

```
$('#closeButton').click(function() {
  if(confirm("CloseWarning")) {
    $('#saveButton').click();
    window.location.href = "main.html";
  } else {
    window.location.href = "main.html";
  }
});
```

However the issue is that the saveButton click event doesn't have enough time to finish before the entire page redirects. So my question is what's the best way to do a callback in this situation so that save button is clicked and then we redirect to the main page.

Comment: What does the save button do? call a javascript function?

Comment: Put the redirect at the end of the save function?

Comment: Some JS and AJAX to pass data to the backend.

Comment: Re: tymeJV, well no because I need to Save button to only Save without the redirect.

Comment: @GOE -- Just thought of that, and musefan covered it with his answer.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your save button calls a javascript function, you could do something like this:

```
function saveFunction(doRedirect){
    //normal save code
    if(doRedirect)
        window.location.href = "main.html";
}
```

NOTE: If your "normal save code" is an AJAX call, you should add the `doRedirect` check in the success callback of your ajax request.

and then you can use like so:

```
$('#closeButton').click(function() {
  if(confirm("CloseWarning")) {
    saveFunction(true);
  } else {
    window.location.href = "main.html";
  }
});
```

---

Alternative approach with your own callback:

```
function saveFuncton(callback){
   //normal save code

   //when done (or on AJAX success)
   if(callback)
      callback(true);//or false if not successful
}
```

and then....

```
$('#closeButton').click(function() {
  if(confirm("CloseWarning")) {
    saveFunction(function(success){
       if(success){
          window.location.href = "main.html";
       }
    });
  } else {
    window.location.href = "main.html";
  }
});
```

---

**The HACKY approach (DO NOT USE UNLESS YOU HAVE ABSOLUTELY NO OTHER ALTERNATIVE)**

```
var isSaving = false;
$(document).ajaxStop(function () {
    if (isSaving) {
        window.location.href = "main.html";
    }
});
```

and then...

```
$('#closeButton').click(function() {
  if(confirm("CloseWarning")) {
    isSaving = true;
    $('#saveButton').click();
  } else {
    window.location.href = "main.html";
  }
});
```

This MIGHT work, but it really depends on how your save function works, and if anything else might be doing an ajax call at the same time. Also, if you save function does more than one AJAX call this method will likely fail. It is a hacky approach, use it at your own risk!

Comment: @GOE: than you have a real problem. If your save if doing an AJAX request you need to wait for that to complete before you navigate to another page. So you need some notification for this. I find it hard to believe you cannot edit it, but one hacky approach could be to monitor all AJAX requests and when it complete (and hope its the correct one) do the navigation

Comment: @musefan I can edit save logic but I'm not allowed to modify it.

Comment: @GOE. That doesn't make sense. Edit = Modify. Perhaps add your save logic to your question

Comment: @musefan it does make sense if you think about it. Yes you can physically edit the code but sometimes you are not allowed to due to office politics, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass data to events when you trigger them, so you could do something like this:

```
$('#closeButton').click(function(e) {
    if(confirm('..')) {
         $('#saveButton').trigger('click', [true]);
    } else {
         window.location.href = "main.html";
    }
});

$('#saveButton').click(function(e, close) {
    // do saving stuff ..
    // for normal clicks "close" will be undefined, otherwise close when done
    if(close) {
        window.location.href = "main.html";
    }
});
```

If you wanted to be more [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) about it, you could have the closing code in the saveButton be a similar trigger to the closeButton with a `force` variable of sorts that would force the close, so you would not repeat the redirect URL in two different parts of the code.

If you can't modify your Save logic (which seems like a questionable thing, but okay...) you could do this, assuming the Save logic consists of a single AJAX call and you don't have any other AJAX requests firing off. If you did, you can check the `settings` variable to make sure its the right one before you close:

```
$('#closeButton').click(function(e) {
    if(confirm('..')) {
         $(document).ajaxComplete(function(e, xhr, settings) {
             window.location.href = "main.html";
         });
         $('#saveButton').click();
    } else {
         window.location.href = "main.html";
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Whatever script is executed on saveButton click, set the response in a variable there, when form is saved. Then check the value of that. Here is the example :

```
$('#closeButton').click(function() {
  if(confirm("CloseWarning")) {
    $('#saveButton').click(function(){
         // Code to save the form 
         if(saved == true){
              window.location.href = "main.html";
         }
    });
  } else {
    window.location.href = "main.html";
  }
});
```